# Self-referring propositions

Tags: logic, truth, paradox

**This proposition is false**

As you can see in the proposition above, there is a problem. This sentence can't be true, but it can't be false either. I believe that this issue comes from the fact that the proposition refers to itself.

My question is: is it valid for a proposition to refer to itself, given that we can obtain things like the example above? Are there any texts on the subject or is it considered as something obvious that a proposition cannot be its own object?

Comment: You can see [Self-Reference](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/) and its bibliography.

Comment: Your assertion "This sentence can't be true" is not correct.  In fact, it is true, that the proposition is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it is okay for a sentence to refer to itself.

Consider:

> This is a sentence.

There doesn't seem to be any problem in saying that it is *true*. Importantly, it can be given a precise form and even proven (e.g. in [PA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms)). One can construct a predicate *Sent(x)* which says of a given *x* that it is a sentence. Now consider the sentence *A*:

> Sent(⌈A⌉)

("⌈A⌉" is used to refer to the sentence *A*. This can be done with [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering).)

This is a well defined self-referring sentence. As noted above, it can also be proven.

So if self-reference is okay, then what's the deal with this:

> This sentence is false.

This leads to a *contradiction* since it can be shown to be both true and false (and not neither of them as you suggested).

This is known as [**the liar paradox**](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/). Some philosophers and logicians (e.g. [Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Tarski), [Kripke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Kripke)) have attributed great importance to it, since it seems to say something about the notion of *truth*. Some of them have attempted to solve it. You can read about these attempts in the above link.

Another great source discussing these issues is [this very good SEP entry on self-reference](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/).

Answer (score 1):

Eliran H's (accepted) answer gives an excellent and interesting response from a classical point of view, and I thought it may also be useful elaborate further on the non-classical views.

Philosophers find it convenient to divide paradoxes into two types; the semantic and the set-theoretic.  Semantic paradoxes express paradoxes of truth, denotation, predication, and the like, while set-theoretic paradoxes express paradoxes of membership and cardinality.

The example you site of "This proposition is false" is (obviously) a semantic paradox.  There are some philosophers, such as [Graham Priest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_Priest) who take the view that semantic paradoxes are *bona fide* sound arguments.  Such a view requires that one adopt a non-classical logic, specifically what is called a [paraconsistent logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic).  According to Priest's methods, if we let **A** denote the statment "This proposition is false", then the proposition **A** ∧ ¬**A** is true.  In other words, both **A** and its negation are true.

Another alternative take on this paradox, as mentioned in Eliran's answer, can be found in the work of [Saul Kripke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Kripke).  While I am not entirely familiar with Kripke's work, I believe that Kripkean analysis would entail that the liar paradox, as stated, is not true, and so, according to Kripke, we should assert this.  On the other hand, Kripke's methods would have nothing to say about the possibility that the proposition is also true, as is the case with Priest's paraconsistent view. As I say, I am not familiar enough with Kripke's work to be certain of my comments so perhaps someone else can elaborate.

Ultimately, I believe that how one views such paradoxes all comes down to is whether or not you accept that natural languages satisfy [Tarski's theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_theory_of_truth#Tarski.27s_theory).